# ld: duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: c++, pointers

I keep getting these errors when I run my tests with multiple c++ files. any help would be appreciated on how to get past these errors. I hear it may be something to do with loading something twice but Im not sure.

I cannot post my code due to assignment restraints.

```
duplicate symbol 'Node::getRow()' in:
    /var/folders/9h/ljy9dhpn2s7g90mv5x5xwcy40000gn/T/Node-2e2741.o
    /var/folders/9h/ljy9dhpn2s7g90mv5x5xwcy40000gn/T/NodeList-4bf0e5.o
duplicate symbol 'Node::getCol()' in:
    /var/folders/9h/ljy9dhpn2s7g90mv5x5xwcy40000gn/T/Node-2e2741.o
    /var/folders/9h/ljy9dhpn2s7g90mv5x5xwcy40000gn/T/NodeList-4bf0e5.o
duplicate symbol 'Node::getDistanceToS()' in:
    /var/folders/9h/ljy9dhpn2s7g90mv5x5xwcy40000gn/T/Node-2e2741.o
    /var/folders/9h/ljy9dhpn2s7g90mv5x5xwcy40000gn/T/NodeList-4bf0e5.o
duplicate symbol 'Node::~Node()' in:
    /var/folders/9h/ljy9dhpn2s7g90mv5x5xwcy40000gn/T/Node-2e2741.o
    /var/folders/9h/ljy9dhpn2s7g90mv5x5xwcy40000gn/T/NodeList-4bf0e5.o
duplicate symbol 'Node::~Node()' in:
    /var/folders/9h/ljy9dhpn2s7g90mv5x5xwcy40000gn/T/Node-2e2741.o
    /var/folders/9h/ljy9dhpn2s7g90mv5x5xwcy40000gn/T/NodeList-4bf0e5.o
duplicate symbol 'Node::Node(int, int, int)' in:
    /var/folders/9h/ljy9dhpn2s7g90mv5x5xwcy40000gn/T/Node-2e2741.o
    /var/folders/9h/ljy9dhpn2s7g90mv5x5xwcy40000gn/T/NodeList-4bf0e5.o
duplicate symbol 'Node::Node(int, int, int)' in:
    /var/folders/9h/ljy9dhpn2s7g90mv5x5xwcy40000gn/T/Node-2e2741.o
    /var/folders/9h/ljy9dhpn2s7g90mv5x5xwcy40000gn/T/NodeList-4bf0e5.o
duplicate symbol 'Node::setDistanceToS(int)' in:
    /var/folders/9h/ljy9dhpn2s7g90mv5x5xwcy40000gn/T/Node-2e2741.o
    /var/folders/9h/ljy9dhpn2s7g90mv5x5xwcy40000gn/T/NodeList-4bf0e5.o
duplicate symbol 'Node::getRow()' in:
    /var/folders/9h/ljy9dhpn2s7g90mv5x5xwcy40000gn/T/Node-2e2741.o
    /var/folders/9h/ljy9dhpn2s7g90mv5x5xwcy40000gn/T/PathPlanner-af1285.o
duplicate symbol 'Node::getCol()' in:
    /var/folders/9h/ljy9dhpn2s7g90mv5x5xwcy40000gn/T/Node-2e2741.o
    /var/folders/9h/ljy9dhpn2s7g90mv5x5xwcy40000gn/T/PathPlanner-af1285.o
duplicate symbol 'Node::getDistanceToS()' in:
    /var/folders/9h/ljy9dhpn2s7g90mv5x5xwcy40000gn/T/Node-2e2741.o
    /var/folders/9h/ljy9dhpn2s7g90mv5x5xwcy40000gn/T/PathPlanner-af1285.o
duplicate symbol 'Node::~Node()' in:
    /var/folders/9h/ljy9dhpn2s7g90mv5x5xwcy40000gn/T/Node-2e2741.o
    /var/folders/9h/ljy9dhpn2s7g90mv5x5xwcy40000gn/T/PathPlanner-af1285.o
duplicate symbol 'Node::~Node()' in:
    /var/folders/9h/ljy9dhpn2s7g90mv5x5xwcy40000gn/T/Node-2e2741.o
    /var/folders/9h/ljy9dhpn2s7g90mv5x5xwcy40000gn/T/PathPlanner-af1285.o
duplicate symbol 'Node::Node(int, int, int)' in:
    /var/folders/9h/ljy9dhpn2s7g90mv5x5xwcy40000gn/T/Node-2e2741.o
    /var/folders/9h/ljy9dhpn2s7g90mv5x5xwcy40000gn/T/PathPlanner-af1285.o
duplicate symbol 'Node::Node(int, int, int)' in:
    /var/folders/9h/ljy9dhpn2s7g90mv5x5xwcy40000gn/T/Node-2e2741.o
    /var/folders/9h/ljy9dhpn2s7g90mv5x5xwcy40000gn/T/PathPlanner-af1285.o
duplicate symbol 'Node::setDistanceToS(int)' in:
    /var/folders/9h/ljy9dhpn2s7g90mv5x5xwcy40000gn/T/Node-2e2741.o
    /var/folders/9h/ljy9dhpn2s7g90mv5x5xwcy40000gn/T/PathPlanner-af1285.o
ld: 16 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Do you *define* (implement) these function in a header file? Are the functions marked as `inline` (explicitly by you, or implicitly by defining the functions inline inside the class definition)? Can you please show us a [mre] (with emphasis in the *minimal* part)?

Comment: I also recommend you learn about the concept of [*translation units*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)).

Comment: This says duplicate symbols, I think if these functions weren't defined in a header file id have this issue. Unfortunately I cant share any sort of code due to the risk it poses to me for this assignment. I have a test.cpp where I run tests, Node.h where classes are initialised and Node.cpp where they are implemented

Comment: "Duplicate symbols" means the symbols are defined (implemented) in multiple translation units. This typically happens if you define (implement) these symbols in a header file. Or wrongly include a *source* file that you also build. Do you have e.g. `#include "Node.cpp"` in your main source file?